# Cucumber: Is it best practice to write step definitions before or after writing methods and classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd

When writing ruby (& ror) applications with BDD, should the step definitions be written before you even create the models, views and controllers in order to save the maximum headache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should - that's the main idea of BDD and TDD, respectively. Red - Green - Refactor. First start off with your feature (e.g. use [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) here), then write the step definitions and finally your code.

[The RSepc Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) is a good read to capture the whole thing. Take at look at figure 1.1 The BDD-cycle on page 29. This gives you a good overview on how to approach BDD and TDD and also has some nice examples.